# A width set to 100% exceeds container in firefox

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I have this annoying problem with a menu. In firefox the "ul" tag exceeds it's parent container. In Chrome and IE it doesn't.

What i want: I want the dropdowns to have the same width as their parent (Open the example in chrome to see how it should look)

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/fYQ4k/7/)

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="/sommer-2013">Sommer 2013</a>
    <ul> <--- This one exceeds it's parent
      <li><a href="/sommer-2013/vinter-2012">Vinter 2012</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="/webshop.html">WEBSHOP</a></li>
  <li><a href="/company.html">COMPANY</a></li>
  <li><a href="/stores.html">STORES</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/biznuge/2vNpE/12/

hacked the guts out of what was in the original fiddle. sorry about that.

After looking at it, I didn't feel the explanations about position:absolute being the issue were quite right with regards to the inheritance of the next relative parent in the DOM, so I tried tinkering with the display mode of the "table-like" structure you had in place.

```
nav{
  /*display: table;*/
}    
nav>ul{ 
  /*display: table-row;*/
}
nav>ul>li{
  /*display: table-cell;*/
}
```

after removing the table, table-row and table-cell displays the width inheritance suddenly began working.

Will take a bit more of a look at this, as I've been using table for a while now to force certain layouts such as menu structures etc.

Good question @dasmikko!

Answer (score 1):

`ul` is a block element, you shouldn't need to set the width at all - by default it will already use the whole width available (which will be 100% - padding). The same goes for `li`.

As for why it's exceeding its container, that's probably due to default padding/margins being different between Firefox, Chrome and IE. If that is the case, just set `padding: 0; margin: 0; border: 0` on `ul`, `li` and `a`.

Comment: I updated the link, to include my CSS re-setter. And removing the width did't do much.

Comment: @dgvid is right, it's because you're using `position: absolute;` You might want to set a fixed width instead in that case - something like 20em seems good. The `li` should expand as needed. Also, your CSS seems far more complicated than it ought to be.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the padding to 0?

The specs say that the padding should be exclusive of the width (IE ignores this, and it seems that possible Chrome does when fitting an object to a container).

Comment: Yes, i just forgot to add it in the jsfiddle link. Updated it now!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is related to the inner `ul` being absolutely positioned. Because it is absolutely positioned, a relative width, i.e., a percentage, is relative to the document itself, not to its container. Don't set the width at all, and the `ul` will be sized to fit its container. Or in other words, removing the width settings from the rule for `nav ul` and for `nav ul li ul`.

As to why this is a problem under Firefox, but not Chrome, I have no idea. Suggestions, anyone?

Comment: But then the next problem comes up, because I want the child ul width to be the same as the parent (li).